# Option value on select new option avaible

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

im looking for a simple javascript with option value, when i select a value a new value will be avaible.

Ex:

I have a list with this options:

```
Anytext1
Anytext2
Anytex3
```

If i select anytext 1 new select options avaible like 1anytext1 2anytext1...

Then if i select anytext2 another select options avaible

Any ideea of a simple customizable script? Or any other ideea?

Where i am using this?
Its a furniture website, if he select sofas, new options avaible like sofa1 sofa2 sofa3, then if he select sofa2 another options apear like color1 color2 color3 etc :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

Using this way you could easily use an ajax call to return data in place of hard coding the arrays of types and colors.

```
<div>
    <label for="item">Item</label>
    <select id="item">
        <option value="">--- Select an Item ---</option>
        <option value="Sofa">Sofa</option>
        <option value="Chair">Chair</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="type">Type</label>
    <select id="type"></select>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="color">Color</label>
    <select id="color"></select>
</div>

<script>

    var types = [];
    var colors = [];

    // Get a reference to the select boxs
    var item = document.getElementById('item');
    var type = document.getElementById('type');
    var color = document.getElementById('color');

    // Add an event handler for when an item is selected
    item.addEventListener('change', function () {

        i = item.options[item.selectedIndex].value;

        if (i == "Sofa") {
            types = [
                { text: "Full Size", value: "full-size" },
                { text: "Love Seat", value: "love-seat" }
            ];
        }

        if (i == "Chair") {
            types = [
                { text: "Standard", value: "standard" },
                { text: "Recliner", value: "recliner" }
            ];
        }

        setOptions(type, types);

    });

    // Add an event handler for when an type is selected
    type.addEventListener('change', function () {

        i = type.options[type.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(type.options[type.selectedIndex].value);

        if (i == "full-size") {
            colors = [
                { text: "Brown", value: "brown" },
                { text: "White", value: "white" },
                { text: "Black", value: "black" }
            ];
        }

        if (i == "love-seat") {
            colors = [
                { text: "Tan", value: "tan" },
                { text: "Red", value: "red" },
                { text: "Copper", value: "copper" }
            ];
        }

        if (i == "standard") {
            colors = [
                { text: "Green", value: "green" },
                { text: "Yellow", value: "yellow" },
                { text: "Red", value: "red" }
            ];
        }

        if (i == "recliner") {
            colors = [
                { text: "Orange", value: "orange" },
                { text: "Purple", value: "purple" },
                { text: "Magenta", value: "magenta" }
            ];
        }

        setOptions(color, colors);

    });

    // Function to add Options
    function setOptions(select, opts) {

        // Clear existing values
        select.innerHTML = "";

        // Add a select option
        var elm = document.createElement('option');
        elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("--- Select an Option"));
        select.appendChild(elm);

        for (o in opts) {
            var opt = opts[o];

            // create new option element
            var elm = document.createElement('option');

            // create text node to add to option element (opt)
            elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode(opt.text));

            // set value property of opt
            elm.value = opt.value;

            // add opt to end of select box (sel)
            select.appendChild(elm);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: wonderfull!!  Thanks alot Jesse James Burton, but is there a way on a selected value a new <select> option to appear?

Comment: Sorry! I have edited my post, i am trying to get a new select option if one select option is selected :D

Comment: Such a fast answear, thanks alot, i was trying alot to find something like this!

Comment: i will try to customize it, if im getting any trouble may i ask you again? :) , how can i give you some "like" im new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Great :) I am glad it helped! Accepting my answer and voting it up (grey arrow beside it) are both super appreciated! 

I have modified it a bit more in a way I think may help you further!

Comment: I have updated it now so that you could change the hard coded arrays to ajax calls if you had a database of types and colors say.

Comment: Great! :) Happy that it will help.

Comment: im developing my site now and i found something xD, any ideea how to do it if "Standard Chair" is selected show only color "Red"? :D

Comment: You could apply the same logic to set selects. So basically instead of setting the type and color when you select the item you would just set the type and then add an eventListener on change to the type which would set the color. Does that make sense?

Comment: It make sense but i got no ideea how to do it :-S i will try it now

Comment: i can't get it, :( do you think you can show me an exemple?

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect this option. This isn't necessarily the way I would recommend doing it if you have a lot of data as it is a little clunky but it will certainly do the trick. Ideally you would create a function that gets the array of options based on the previous value passed in. Does that make sense? So this is pretty hard coded but instead you could re-write it as a function that goes and gets an array which is then passed to the setOptions function. :)

Comment: Yes, it will be a very hard codding because i have like 9 type of sofas, 4 type of arm chair 3 type of mini sofas :-S and like 45 type of furniture, most of them use different colors and other options like on sofas the handdle size etc